# How can I read and parse a URL's XML or JSON content with C++?

Tags: c++, xml, json, parsing, xmlreader

I can easily do this with JQuery or PHP but I have a project for my Intro to C++ class and I thought it'll be pretty cool if I could mix C++ with some APIs like twitter, google, yahoo etc.

Could you tell me if there is a class ( I know OOP ) I can use to read an external XML or JSON file. The program has to run on windows and linux so I can't use commands.

Or, if this can't be done, what other cool project would you do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

XML: xerces(C++) http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/

JSON:http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoncpp/